# logs are not getting written in log file when I specify command in crontab with bash script

Tags: bash, python-2.7, unit-testing, cron

When I scheduled below command in crontab, the test cases are running fine. But it does not write the log file specified below.

```
30 03 * * * user cd /home/common_setupwise_testcases && bash setup_wise_test.sh >> /home/testing/cron_logs/setup_wise_test_cases.log
```

I already tried this: `/home/testing/cron_logs/setup_wise_test_cases.log 2>&1`, and I got this output:

```
{"timestamp": "2017-10-23T10:25:01.387967Z", "event": "2017-10-23", "_": {"ln": 34, "file": "common_mail_triggering.py", "name":"__main__", "fn": "sub_process"}, "level": "error"}
```

But I want this below format to store in logfile

```
test_logout (testing_logout.LogOut) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.458s

OK
```

Comment: `>> /home/testing/cron_logs/setup_wise_test_cases.log 2>&1`

Comment: Hi, it's not a duplicate question.
I edited further. Please read again and post your suggestions.